# Where to set Mindray BC-5150 HL7 communication port number and ip address

Tags: c#, tcp, lis

I'm working on a LIS TCP communication service with the Mindray BC-5150 laboratory device, and I could not found where to put the communication settings (service address and port number),but I did found where to set the network settings of the device itself (ip address, mask ...)

So my question is the following :

- How to set the ip address and the port number for HL7 communication service in the mindray BC-5150 ?
- If there is no such settings, is there really a way to establish tcp communication knowing just the ip address of the device ? I guess some port scanning is required if I'm not mistaking.

Note : Same for the Mindray bs-20

Comment: The device IP address (mask) need to be in the same subnet as the PC.  You are asking the question backwards.  You need to set the device IP address so it is in your network.  If the device is connected to the same router as you PC then route to machine will automatically will be found using ARP protocol.  If the device is not in same subnet than a route need to device has to exist.  It is no different than connecting a network printer.

Comment: Okay @jdweng, I'll test this tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @jdweng : Today I've edit the device settings to be in the same subnet, the network connection passed, but the communication failed (error connecting to network). I'm gessing it's a port issue

Comment: From cmd.exe use >Ping IP and see if there is a connection.  If you are directly connecting to the device from machine you need a cross over ethernet cable.  If both the PC and device are connected to a router than you use a regular ethernet cable.  A cross over cable in the one connector of the cable two wires will be crossed over so you will have a null modem.   The cable is usually marked or is colored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In BC-5150, port number is fixed and it is 5100

Comment: I'll test that asap, thanks. Is there a way to put the server ip address ? or the device will scan the network for a computer where the port 5100 is available ?

Comment: Analyzer always act as the server. Your LIS PC should act as a client. You can get the analyzers' IP address in the Communication setup screen in the analyzer.

Comment: In the BC-5150 communication protocol, it's said that the analyzer send the sample results to the LIS computer once completed, this can be automatically or manually (ORU^R01). To which I have to responde with an ACK. So how the analyzer know where to send sample results (my LIS computer address) ? I've worked with the BC-5300 before, and the setting were simple (lis ip address and port number). Thanks again.

Comment: The connection is requested by the client machine to the server to connect through the socket. Once the handshake is completed, the server will push the results through that socket to the client pc. So no need to configure a client ip in the server side (from analyzer)

Comment: I've used the TCPClient c# class to connected to the analyzer on port 5100 and it worked perfectly. Thanks. I've got another question if you may, The next analyzer I'll work on is the Mindray BS-20, does it have the same port ? or more generaly, how to know witch port is used by the analyzer ?

Comment: Some analyzers, the port can be configured in the analyzer settings. If not, the dedicated port is mentioned in the interface manual of each analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here, I am using mirth connect on my computer. I understand that BC 5150 has the port set to port 5100 and the Analyzer always act as the server while LIS PC should act as a client.

Now how do i send an initial socket connection request from the Mirth TCP listener to the Analyzer so that the analyzer now knows where to send its results.

I have some java code to establish the connection but where do i put it?
and how will the analyzer know which port to client is listening on ?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String AnalyzerIP = "192.168.1.100";
            int AnalyzerPort = 5150;

            Socket socket = new Socket(AnalyzerIP, AnalyzerPort);

            // Now you have a socket connection to your Mirth server!
            // You can send data over this socket.

            // Close the socket when done:
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

from the above answers; "Once the handshake is completed, the server will push the results through that socket to the client pc. " But how does the server know which port the client pc is listening on?

This is quite confusing to me. I have also worked with other analyzers before, and the setting was simple since the Analyzer had an interface to enter the exact LIS ip address and port number to send results.

Comment: So I posted my issue on Mirth Connect Github page and @jonbartels solved the issue by suggesting that i setup a TCP Listener running in "client mode"  and it worked.


Here is the link he pointed me to: https://docs.nextgen.com/bundle/Mirth_User_Guide_41/page/connect/connect/topics/c_TCP_Listener_connect_ug.html